# Python statsmodels ARIMA Prediction

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, statsmodels

I am using the Python statsmodels library to generate ARIMA models for the first time. I have a data array called data that contains 50 values that I would like to train the model on and then I would like to predict the next several values. I wrote code like this:

```
from statsmodels import tsa as tsa
p = 1
d = 0
q = 1
temp = tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(data.dropna().values, [p, d, q])
model = temp.fit(trend='c' , disp = False)
```

If I run:

```
model.predict()
```

I get an array of 50 values. Are these the models predictions for the 50 values I calibrated the model with? I read the documentation found here:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict

As I understand it writing the following code would generate a prediction for the next step:

```
model.predict(start=0, end=0)
```

Is this logic correct and is the code doing what I expect? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could try the `forecast` method which does out of sample prediction. For `predict`, start would have to be the index after the length of your estimation/training sample if you don't use time indices, IIRC.

Comment: So if I call predict with no parameters what are those 50 values?

Comment: What is the difference between using forecast and predict then?

Comment: predict without arguments returns the fitted values for the estimation sample.

Comment: The difference between using forecast and predict is that `predict` is the general method in most models to predict new observations including insample predictions. `forecast` is specific to time series and predicts the next observations that follow the estimation sample. Most other models don't have a predefined sequence for the observations like time periods.